# Fields to 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with SQL server 2014 and SSIS and I need to do the following:

I have one table with this info:

```
Location |Location Type |Region | World Region
1        |        A     |   EU  |  EU
36       |        V     |   AM  |   AM
24       |        S     |   AS  |  AS
26       |        G     |   AJ  |   AJ
```

and I need to get the next result

```
Locations

'1,A,EU,EU'
'36,V,AM,AM'
'24,S,AS,AS'
'26,G,AJ,AJ'
```

Does anybody know an alternative? I'm saving save into a variable the table name, so every table has different number of columns and I need to do this in 8 table.

Comment: You are looping though 8 tables in SSIS and want to save each table as a CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dynamic query

```
DECLARE @tblName VARCHAR(20) = 'your_tbl_name'
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns, '') + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '], '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tblName

SET @sql = 'SELECT CONCAT(' + STUFF(@columns, LEN(@columns), 1, '') + ') FROM ' + @tblName
EXEC(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use the [`CONCAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) function with commas in between the fields. In your example, you'd want something like:

`SELECT CONCAT(Location, ',', LocationType, ',', Region, ',', WorldRegion) AS Locations FROM ...`

Comment: Yeah that's the solution,but I forgot to mention that I am working with SSIS and I save into a variable the table name, so every table has different number of columns and I need to do this in 8 table

Comment: If you just need to turn every query result into a CSV, more or less, I would suggest moving that burden into a script or a program rather than trying it directly on the database layer.